# What if time and quantum corrections were created because the idea of "god" was damaged?

Tags: quantum-physics, quantum-interpretations, existence-of-god

Assuming the idea of "God" exists. In its most perfect form, should physics not be without the various quantum phenomena with a renormalizable gravitational theory? Perhaps the idea of imperfections that quantum mechanics brings are a manifestation of something affecting a singular but perfect being that led to the big bang. Thus, we go from complete order (God) to a level of disorder that is increasing as maybe "God" is dying?

Comment: I'm a massive fan of original ideas, but this question (I think) asks for imagination and opinion as opposed to material from the literature. Is there any reading you've done which might ground your question in existing work?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such literature. Although a paper "Gods as topological insulators" may be relevant.

Comment: Your post is not intelligible. I guess you mean to assume that "*god exists*" rather than "*the idea [itself] 'of god' exists*". Regardless, in Physics there is no assumption about a god. Hence introducing it here so lightheartedly results in too many gaps. What do you mean by imperfections? The limited accuracy of measurement implies nothing about the perfection of the measured system. What led to the big bang? some manifestation [and of what]? or the "perfect being"? Lastly, you might want to provide a link to the paper you mention.

Comment: Once you assume God exists, anything is possible.  Once you assume God doesn't exist, then you are limited by human observations and analysis for information about the universe.

Answer (score 1):

This is one formulation of perhaps the most well-known and intractable problem in theology, the "Problem of Evil." The basic concept is "how could a good and perfect (and all-powerful) God create anything less than perfect?"  Normally, that's couched in terms of moral imperfections, but it's the same underlying argument in terms of physical imperfections as well.

It's only a problem for conceptions of God as perfect and all-powerful, which are not universal. In particular, it's a problem for Platonism/neo-Platonism. The two solutions Plato provided is that the world we experience is just an illusion, and that it was created not by the supreme deity, but by a "demiurge" or imperfect lesser deity. These solutions, however, are somewhat less than satisfying, since they don't explain how illusions or a demiurge could come to be.

In Christianity, the classic explanation of imperfection in the world is "Original Sin," and the idea that human beings' imperfect choices are tied to the greater good of free will. In Zoroastrianism, and in some variants of Christianity, evil is blamed on an evil deity, or the devil (who thus must be conceptualized as powerful enough to vie with God). In some versions of Islam, similar to Plato, what appears as imperfection is considered to be just a misunderstanding or ignorance of the perfection of God's plan. In the same way, what you see as the quantum imperfections of the universe might only be your ignorance failing to recognize perfection when you see it.

In summary, you've hit upon a venerable problem.  Your take on it is unusual, but not unique--I've encountered it before, but not in any sources I am able to confidently identify. With that said, philosophers including Hegel and most famously Nietzsche have previously discussed the concept of [a non-immortal deity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_is_dead).

Comment: The implicit theology of the Cosmere saga (Brandon Sanderson) imports talk of a god being broken into "shards," from some Jewish arcana, with the "shards" manifesting as spiritual deficits in the world (or something along that line). Those are the two narratives that strike the same chord, for me, as the OP...

Answer (score 0):

If an actual God were lurking within physics, then physics as a scientific and mathematical discipline would cease to exist because that god could then enable or prevent anything on a whim, and so a mathematically predictive and consistent description of the world would not be possible.

The fact that a quantum gravity model based on the formalisms of quantum field theory hasn't been found yet (despite decades of dedicated searching) does not require an explanation along the lines of "because god". It simply suggests that there is a key concept that is missing in the models constructed so far. Our job is to search for that concept; giving up and handing it all over to god is the ultimate cop-out.

In this context it is well to remember that just 3000 years ago, humans thought they could make it rain by dancing and that god could be pleased (whatever that might mean) by burning a piece of meat on a mountaintop. Time has shown that in both those cases, several key concepts were missing.

Answer (score 0):

> What if time and quantum corrections were created because the idea of "god" was damaged?

Presuming "idea of god" exists like a form in Plato's realm of forms, such creation of time and quantum corrections would exist as evidence that not all forms (presuming more than one has existed) exist as immune to damage.

> Thus, we go from complete order (God) to a level of disorder that is increasing as maybe "God" is dying?

If God exists as the realm of forms (and a form can be damaged), I could see the reasoning for such an argument.

It doesn't seem likely the realm of forms exists, but I've often speculated that reality exists as a superorganism. Relate that to information systems theory, claim that all of it works together as an organism, and you have "God."